# SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation, MOF Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 and I get the following error

> MOF Syntax Error.

And it happends when it gets to the "provider_Cpu32_WMI something.."

Does anyone know how I can fix this, I have tried the whole day with no luck..

Things I have tried,

- Manually uninstalling SQL Server 2008 R2 by using Add/Remove Programs, deleting folders, deleting registry keys, etc....
- I checked on google and many people had have problems with this... but I have tried it all with no luck.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a [slipstream](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/petersad/archive/2010/05/31/rrr.aspx) install that has the CUs?  I bet all the money in my pockets (25 cents mind you) that this will resolve the issue.